# How to configure nginx to work with Jetty6 webserver?

Tags: nginx, jetty

It seems that nginx is used with php, ruby and python.

Anyone has an example of how to setup nginx to work with jetty/tomcat in backend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx can forward via HTTP protocol, so just point it to the correct port and you're set:

```
server {
    location /anything {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I was typing my own answer as you posted yours. It's my first go at nginx. Thank you.

Comment: It is not the right answer anymore!
As of right now (jetty9.3) you must use `proxy_redirect  off;` like @Florin showed below.l

Answer (score 19):

Right. I guess I qualify as a self learner, don't I.

Just add these lines within the http { } scope of the nginx.conf file:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx_67_log main;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

I have to try now gzip, SSL and dojo cometd and see if I can upgrade to nginx.
Any clues are welcome.