# any way to configure jetty behind nginx but only for "active content"?

Tags: java, servlets, nginx, jetty

I'm new to both jetty and nginx. They seem lightweight and high performance. But I would like to configure nginx to pass request to jetty only when those are handled by a servlet. Letting nginx deal with those .jpg, .css, .js, and so on.

I can do that with resin/tomcat + Apache but can't find it for nginx+jetty.

**EDIT** I found exactly this in [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That another [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266931/how-to-configure-nginx-to-work-with-jetty6-webserver), could give you a way to setup nginx. And you use a different *path* for your static content: images, js, css..